# Close the app by hardware back button on Ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to make my app close on  back button 
I found this code in github

```
 //Called when view is loaded as ionViewDidLoad() removed from Ionic v4
  ngOnInit(){
    this.initializeBackButtonCustomHandler();
  }


  //Called when view is left
  ionViewWillLeave() {
    // Unregister the custom back button action for this page
    this.unsubscribeBackEvent && this.unsubscribeBackEvent();
  }

  initializeBackButtonCustomHandler(): void {
    this.unsubscribeBackEvent = this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(999999,  () => {
        alert("back pressed home" + this.constructor.name);
    });
    /* here priority 101 will be greater then 100 
    if we have registerBackButtonAction in app.component.ts */
  }
```

It works , but on all pages

I want to restrict it only on home page

I used `this.constructor.name == HomePage` but not work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above Code works, but i think you write it to the wrong Place. Subscribe to the BackButton on the OnInit or ionViewDidEnter Methode of the Home Page and unsubscribe on the OnDestroy or ionPageWillLeave.

Otherwise: You don't have to need such a high Priority. The default is Zero. Every Higher would work. If you use this Methode on multiple Pages and Components you should think about a Priority-Logic.

Comment: I unsubscribed it on "ionPageWillLeave" and it works fine